# Having trouble converting from string to LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, string, mfc

I am trying to put some text in a Static Text widget, like this:

```
m_StartupTime.SetWindowText(someStringVariable);
```

And get an error:

> 'CWnd::SetWindowTextA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'LPCTSTR'

I have tried using the `c.str()` method, but when I do, the program compiles fine, but crashes at run-time, throwing an error:

[image: The error]

So I'm figuring out if the problem is related to the conversion, or anything other than that?

Using CString doesn't solve the problem, and I have tried switching from Unicode charcter set to Multi-Byte, with no success. Oh, I am developing in MFC.

EDIT: Found a solution! I used the CString class.

```
string a = "smth";
CString str(a.c_str());
```

Comment: have you checked `someStringVariable` ? could be corrupted

Comment: str.c_str() gives you a const char *, which is an LPCSTR (Long pointer to C String). So your problem is not in this function, but somewhere else.

Comment: `m_StartupTime.SetWindowText(CString(someStringVariable.c_str()));`

Comment: Something confuses me in your question. Is your project Unicode or not? What of these two will compile `m_StartupTime.SetWindowText("")` or `m_StartupTime.SetWindowText(L"")`?

Comment: Dialecticus: the second one. It's Unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Assert dialog shows you where the assertion is happening: file winocc.cpp, line 246.

Looking through the code, this is the line in that file:

```
ENSURE(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL));
```

It seems your assertion has nothing to do with the string, but the control isn't there (yet?), i.e. the control window isn't valid or does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
CA2T str( someStringVariable.c_str() );
m_StartupTime.SetWindowText(str);
```

Assuming that someStringVariable has std::string  type. Include AtlBase.h to compile this.